# What kind of c function is this?

Tags: c, function, construct

I was reading "Compiler Design in C" book. In the basics section I found a c snippet for lexer something like this -

```
static int Lookahead = -1;
int match(token)
int token;
{
 if(Lookahead == -1)
    Lookahead = lex();

 return token == Lookahead;
}

void advance(){
   Lookahead = lex();
}
```

I got confuse about how this match function get compiled on gnu gcc. So I wrote a function that looks like

```
int a(token)
int token;
{
 printf("Value of token is %d", token);
}
int main()
{
 printf("Hello world!\n");
 a(1);
 return 0;
}
```

And I am getting following output-

Hello world!
Value of token is 1

But I dont getting the reason behind that function declaration. What the benefit of declaring function this way? And how the value of token being 1? Why its not a compile error? Is it some kind of function declaration in C?

Thanks for checking my question. Any kind of help will be great.

Comment: Shimul, your question sent me off on a trip down memory lane delving into the history of the C programming language.  That history can be traced starting from here http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/  enjoy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its an old and deprecated K&R style of function declaration.

```
int match(token)
int token;
{
    // Function body
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int match(int token)
{
    // Function body
}
```

except that in former, compiler would not check that the function is called with the right number of arguments nor will it check the types of arguments. It rely on default argument promotions.
C89 and C99 support this style too.

Comment: @mafso; Latter is not function prototype. Its a complete function definition.

Comment: @mafso; Yes. I know there is difference in parameter checking. Added that part to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is the original way that C functions used to be declared when Kernighan and Ritchie first developed the C programming language. It is referred to as 'K&R C'

C went through a standardisation process and this form of function declaration was changed to the one that you are used to.

On the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language the first edition of the book would have had the old style function declarations, I think it was dropped in the second edition.

Answer (score 3):

Function definitions in the original K&R C were simpler. In your example, the type declaration for function parameter token is actually redundant. The code could be simplified this way:

```
static int Lookahead = -1;
int match(token) {
    if (Lookahead == -1)
        Lookahead = lex();
    return token == Lookahead;
}
void advance(){
   Lookahead = lex();
}
```

Indeed the function return type and variable types also defaulted to int, void was not yet invented, the return statement was optional... leading to further simplification:

```
static Lookahead=-1;
match(token){
  if(Lookahead==-1) Lookahead=lex();
  return token==Lookahead;
}
advance(){Lookahead=lex();}
```

Such primitive style was more compact, but was quite error prone and is no longer supported by modern conforming compilers. The function definition syntax in your example is still supported, but considered obsolete and likely to disappear at some point.